# how can I sort by alphabetically the items of a wxListCtrl simply?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

can anyone give me a short explanation about how to sort by alphabetically the items of a wxListCtrl? I think that I found a way but it seems too complicated.

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Just use the `wxLC_SORT_ASCENDING` style and supply your own comparison function. http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_list_ctrl.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the style as mentioned in the comment and you also can use `SortItems` method

like this:

```
listCtrl->SortItems(CompareFunction, 0);
```

When compare function should act similar to `strcmp`:

```
int wxCALLBACK CompareFunction(wxIntPtr item1, wxIntPtr item2, wxIntPtr WXUNUSED(sortData))
{
  if(item1<item2) return -1;
  if(item1>item2) return 1; 
  if(item1==item2) return 0;
}
```

Comment: Notice that `SortItems()` arguments are the data associated with the items, so you need to use `SetItemData()` to give it something to sort on.