# Sorting wxListCtrl alphabetically without using SetItemData

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I've implemented a `wxListCtrl` and would like to sort the list alphabetically. Although this sounds similar as the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476869/how-can-i-sort-by-alphabetically-the-items-of-a-wxlistctrl-simply), it is different with one major difference: I'm using `SetItemData()` and `GetItemData()` to store the index of a vector.

The code supplied [here](http://www.archivum.info/comp.soft-sys.wxwindows/2006-01/00190/Re-Is-there-an-example-for-sorting-a-wxListCtrl-by-a-column.html) works nicely, but requires `GetItemData()`. Even though the comparison function does not refer to any of the item data, if I omit it, the sorting is not complete.

```
static int wxCALLBACK MyCompareFunction(long item1, long item2, long sortData) {
    wxSortedListCtrl *ctrl = (wxSortedListCtrl*) sortData;
    wxString a, b;
    a = ctrl->GetItemText(item1, ctrl->GetSortedColumn());
    b = ctrl->GetItemText(item2, ctrl->GetSortedColumn());
    if( ctrl->IsSortedAscending() )
        return a.CmpNoCase(b);
    return b.CmpNoCase(a);
}

bool wxSortedListCtrl::SortItems(void) {
    long item = -1;
    for ( ;; ) {
        item = GetNextItem(item);
        if ( item == -1 )
            break;
        SetItemData(item, item);
        //this is needed even though MyCompareFunction doesn't use it AT ALL.
        //however it overwrites the data that I use myself...
    }
    return wxListCtrl::SortItems(MyCompareFunction, (long)this);
}
```

How would I use this sort function while maintaining the item data I've set myself with `SetItemData()`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rely on the control to do the sorting (as opposed to resorting the items internally and just reinserting them into it in the correct order), you must be able to access the sort key (i.e. text in your case) via the item data. So, instead of just associating your own data with each item, associate some struct containing both the item text and your custom data with it.

Alternatively, use `wxLC_VIRTUAL` and just override `OnGetItemXXX()` to return the items in the correct order. This may sometimes be simpler than dealing with sorting the items manually and is definitely much more efficient for any non-trivial number of items.